# Where can I sell Amazon.com Gift Code for Bitcoins?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Where can I sell Amazon.com Gift Code for Bitcoins ? I want a list of services, not exchange sites/forums.

Answer (score 1):

[bitmit.net](http://www.bitmit.net/en/q/?q=amazon) has quite a few gift cards already listed for sale, therefore with the right price you will be able to sell yours with no problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Serith, but I have already tried this site. No luck !

Comment: There is a banner saying that the website will shut down on Decemeber 20, 2013, although it appears that most functionality has already been disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the #bitcoin-otc channel on IRC:

- http://bitcoin-otc.com/